# Storing listView visibility in sharedPreferences

Tags: android

```
SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.
getDefaultSharedPreferences(ClassName.this);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
editor.putString("Info", String.valueOf(List1.getVisibility()));
editor.putString("Office", String.valueOf(List2.getVisibility()));
editor.putString("Education", String.valueOf(List3.getVisibility()));
```

1. Why is the `List1.getVisibility()` returns me `0` when visible and `8` when hidden?
2. Am i storing the right way, the visibility in the SharedPreferences.How would i retrive the values`onCreate()` of my activity.Should i do a
   `if /else` check for each `ListView` or can i do something better.

Comment: You should use `editor.putInt()` instead of `editor.putString()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it returns to you one of the constants `View.VISIBLE`, `View.INVISIBLE`, or `View.GONE`

8 is the value for the [View.GONE](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#GONE) constant, so that is why you are getting 8 when your view is set to gone.

To apply the values from your shared prefs you should be able to do something like this:

```
List1.setVisibility(preferences.getInt("Info", View.VISIBLE));
```

Where the second parameter of getInt() is the default value that you want to use in the event that the preferences does not exist yet.

Comment: Also don't forget about `editor.commit()` or `editor.apply()`

Comment: Should i do a preferences.commit() or editor.commit(). SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(ClassName.this);  List1.setVisibility(preferences.getInt("Info", View.VISIBLE));

Comment: `editor.commit()` and you have to put it after your `editor.putInt()` method calls in the code that you posted.